# error while installing php7 FPM

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04

I have a server with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. Righ now I'm trying to install Nginx+PHP7. I follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04-es) instructions (so sorry that is in spanish, but you can see the commands at least). 
The thing is, when I execute:

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm php-mysql
```

I get this error in the end:
[image]

What should I do? why it cannot instal php-fpm ?

Comment: If you read all the error messages this will become obvious to you. It also tells you what commands to run to get additional information. It looks like there's a previous installation in the way, and I wonder if the version manager is in an inconsistent state.

Comment: You need to scroll back to the original error.

Comment: In the future please use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, often attracts better answers  more quickly and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.